Is there a way to import components from an CDN?
I'm trying to build something where the components are reusable and always updated across different React projects, even after the build.
Would importing components from a CDN be possible?
I know it's probably not the best solution, but I'm open to ideas to achieve the objective.
For example:
import { Button } from 'https:/unpkg.com/:package@:version/:file'
<Button />


I don't think so its possible, to have "the components are reusable and always updated across different ... projects" you need to create a component library. And yes, you will have to update the library in the individual projects.
Also it's risky to update the component on the fly, you would never know if it is going to break your project. What happens if the component needs new prop which is required.

This totally depends on project setup, which is unknown. Why does it have vue tag?  This sounds like XY problem. If you have a proper CI/CD pipeline there shouldn't be problems with updating them. Fwiw, unpkg is down on regular basis, I wouldn't touch it with ten feet pole for vital tasks. You can just use globals and alias imports to them if you want, again, depending on the setup

Definitely feasible but probably not a good idea in terms of performance, reliability, tooling etc etc... Prefer a components library that you would include everywhere.
